# Twitter request

Tags: twitter, twitter-api

Столкнулся с проблемой - надо сделать запрос, который должен получить на выходе не только твиты, где пользователь был упомянут, но и твиты, написанные самим пользователем.

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! пожалуйста, переведите вопрос на русский язык. это можно сделать, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос должен быть следующего вида:
**@userName OR from:userName**